# knitr::include_graphics() can find image files in RStudio but not in rendered html report

Tags: knitr

When I execute a chunk in an RStudio session there is no problem:
[image]

But in the rendered report I see only the broken image icon
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving my figs/ directory into the same directory as the Rmd file solved the issue.

knitr::include_graphics('figs/calc_200.png')